# How to appear a pop-up only once / browser?

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, popup

I got a problem.
I want to show a pop-up image, at the main page of my website only once. If i reload the page, the image should not appear, but it appear again. How can i solve this problem? I tried with session cookie but it didn't help me.

```js
    document.cookie = 'cookie=appear';
    
    if (document.cookie = 'cookie=appear' == 'cookie=appear'){
    function close_function(){
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";    
        document.cookie = 'cookie=notappear';
    }
    }
    if (document.cookie = 'cookie=notappear' == 'notappear'){
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
<div id="popup" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 100px;"><a href="https://www.google.com/"><img class="alignleft" src="folder/picture.jpg" width="300" height="207"></a><button id="close" type="closebutton" onclick="close_function()">X</button></div>
```

I can close the popup, but if i go to other page at my site  and than go back it appear again, and I don't want to show it again. Just only once/browser.

I mean, if i close the Google chrome and reopen the website, the pop up should appear again. Any ideas?

Comment: What is this line of code meant to be doing? `if (document.cookie = 'cookie=appear' == 'cookie=appear'){`

Comment: If the cookie value is equal with the declared value, you can click the button to close the img. After that we change the value of the cookie to not open this if again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use a Bootstrap Modal instead? It helps heaps and could save a lot of time:)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Using modal will be a good idea, but how do i switch of the background fade?

Comment: @Attila5003
Perhaps you should try customizing the Bootstrap opacity using CSS


`.modal-backdrop
{
    opacity:1 !important;
}`

`!important` prevents the opacity from being overwritten - particularly from Bootstrap in this context.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that whenever you reload the page you run this piece of code:

```
document.cookie = "cookie=appear";
```

So whatever the cookie was it would have been set to "cookie=appear";

```js
const popup = document.getElementById("popup");

if(document.cookie == '' || document.cookie == 'cookie=appear') {
     popup.style.display = "inline";
} else {
     popup.style.display = "none";
}

function close_function() {
     document.cookie = "cookie=notappear";
     popup.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 100px;"><a href="https://www.google.com/"><img class="alignleft" src="folder/picture.jpg" width="300" height="207"></a><button id="close" type="closebutton" onclick="close_function()">X</button></div>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use LocalStorage for storing info/recording the number of visits

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. Could you write the code, how you imagined it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try using the Bootstrap Modal then customize its opacity using CSS

`.modal-backdrop { opacity:1 !important; }`

`!important` prevents the opacity from being overwritten - particularly from Bootstrap in this context.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.